# How to run pyRAPL on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, module, sudo

I'm working on a Linux machine.
I need to use pyRAPL with python3.8.
I have installed pyRAPL. The installation was successful.
I went into interpreter (`Python3.8`) and checked. It imports.

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: ’/sys/class/powercap/intel-ra[l/intel-rapl:0/energy_uj'`

So to get around this error I run the code as `sudo python3.8 foo.py`, but when I do that I get the `module not found` error for numpy.

Now it doesn't matter which module I import. When I run the code with `sudo python3.8 foo.py` command, whichever module is there on the first line of my python script, it takes that, and throws a "module not found" error with that. (yes, I tested this).

So this isn't a NumPy specific question.

Now I can run the code just as `python3.8 foo.py` but this will give me the pyRAPL File Permission error. I need to use the pyRAPL library for my project so I can't just comment that out and go ahead.

So I'm stuck in a loop.

No sudo = pyRAPL file permission error.

Yes sudo = module not found error.

Please help me.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Okay. Thanks @Haem. Didn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You report two problems.

1. The Permission error can be resolved with `$ sudo chmod -R a+r /sys/class/powercap/intel-rapl` or with the similar command `$ sudo chown -R energy /sys/class/powercap/intel-rapl`.
2. The Not Found error can be fixed by ensuring root uses same $PATH as your energy user.

Rather than doing global installs for whole server,
consider using [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html).
Then adjusting PATH would be a matter of `$ conda activate my-rapl-env`,
whether you are root or an ordinary user.

Comment: thanks a lot! It worked. The permission command worked. I'll also look into using conda.